# Cannot load the camera for the second time in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing a simple program which loads an external camera through USB connection. When I run the program for the first time, it loads the camera and executes the rest of the code successfully. But if I stop the execution and try to re-run the program, it doesn't load the camera. Yet, if I remove the USB cable and plug it again, the program runs perfectly (The error still occurs if I re-run the program)

Below is my implementation,

```
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract
import imutils

capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
temperature = 0
tot = 0

for i in range(10):

    _, frame = capture.read()

    frame = imutils.resize(image=frame, width=500)
    frame_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_gray = frame_gray[:50, :88]
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)

    try:
        temperature = float(pytesseract.image_to_string(frame_gray))
        tot = tot + temperature
    except ValueError:
        print('except')
    cv.imshow('Frame', frame_gray)

    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

print(tot / 10)

capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

And below is the generated error when I run the program for the second time

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (372) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147023901
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (384) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147023901
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (912) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147023901
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Studies\OpenCV\Lab07\Lab.py", line 15, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(image=frame, width=500)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

So basically I have to plug out and plug in the USB cable in order to re-run the program. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

in first time try to use the method cv.VideoCapture.open and check that it returns True or in the same principle use cv.VideoCapture.isOpened

using open() method call release() before opening a new device

```
capture = cv.VideoCapture()
capture.open(0)
if not capture.IsOpened() :
   ...

...
capture.release()
```

warning be sure to call release() before exit the script
the problem can also come from your camera, check with another one